# How does one run a program using qemu from a bitbake recipe?

Tags: cmake, lua, yocto, qemu, bitbake

I am trying to compile a program that uses CMake and which, as part of its build process, uses the Lua compiler `luac` to compile several Lua scripts. The compiler is found using the `find_program` function from CMake which works nicely when compiling locally. However, when cross-compiling in Yocto, the `find_program` is told not to search in the root path according to [this article](https://www.embeddeduse.com/2017/06/03/cmake-cross-compilation-based-on-yocto-sdk/), resulting in the compiler not being found by CMake (when run from inside Yocto).

This makes sense, since the programs compiled for the target are supposed to be run on the target and will not necessarily execute on the development architecture. So, to the best of my understanding, what I need to do here is to invoke QEMU to run `luac` for me. This is also important since `luac` must execute on an architecture similar to the target (same byte order, same word length) in order for its output to be compatible with the target architecture.

I am sure this information is out there, but due to the fact that QEMU is also used to test entire images, it's almost impossible to find anything about it.

Comment: I think [this](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Technical_FAQ#I_have_some_software_which_needs_to_build_a_binary_that_it_then_runs_as_part_of_its_own_build_process.2C_how_do_I_make_this_work.3F) is part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Update: This answer is incorrect.** As pointed out by @Jussi Kukkonen, while everything builds and the output from the Lua compiler is installed in the image, the compiled Lua byte code will be for the host and *not* for the target. The Lua byte code will only execute correctly if the host and the target happen to share the same word length (and perhaps also endianess).

---

I believe I got this to work, the trick was for the target recipe to `DEPEND` on `lua-native` and to `RDEPEND` on `lua`, i.e.,

```
DEPENDS = "lua-native"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "lua"
```

With this in the recipe, CMake's `find_program` seems to have no problems locating `luac` and compiling the Lua source code. If you are doing something similar, these code snippets might be useful:

Modification to FindLua.cmake to find the correct version of `luac` and to set a `LUA_COMPILER` variable:

```
if (LUA_VERSION_STRING)
  set(_lua_compiler_names
    luac${LUA_VERSION_MAJOR}${LUA_VERSION_MINOR}
    luac${LUA_VERSION_MAJOR}.${LUA_VERSION_MINOR}
    luac-${LUA_VERSION_MAJOR}.${LUA_VERSION_MINOR}
    luac.${LUA_VERSION_MAJOR}.${LUA_VERSION_MINOR}
    )
endif ()

find_program(LUA_COMPILER
  NAMES ${_lua_compiler_names} luac
  NAMES_PER_DIR
  HINTS
    ENV LUA_DIR
  PATH_SUFFIXES bin
)
unset(_lua_compiler_names)
```

I also add `LUA_COMPILER` to the `FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS` `REQUIRED_VARS` variable as follows:

```
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(
 Lua
 REQUIRED_VARS LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR LUA_COMPILER
 VERSION_VAR LUA_VERSION_STRING)
```

Finally, I call the Lua compiler from CMake and install its output as follows:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lua_library.luac
  COMMAND ${LUA_COMPILER} -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lua_library.luac ${SOURCES_LUA_LIBRARY}
  DEPENDS ${SOURCES_LUA_LIBRARY}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_custom_target(lualibrary ALL DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lua_library.luac)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lua_library.luac DESTINATION path/to/install/lua_library/)
```

Comment: (disclaimer: I know very little about lua). When you use a native tool it will naturally run on the build host architecture. So if you plan to ship any bytecode produced by lua-native you will run into problems trying to run it on target... if on the other hand your build system just happens to use lua and everything you ship is non-arch-specific, then everything should be fine